# PHP return array | Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently building a response class with PHP to communicate with my backend API if everything went alright. This is the class:

```
public static function Success($data = null)
{

    if (!$data) {
        return [
            'result'  => true
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            'result' => true,
            'data' => $data
        ];
    }
}
```

But when someone tries to install the plugin on a website it gives the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in filename on line 13,

Line 13 is where the first bracket `[` starts at the first return.

Does anyone know why I get this error? I think it has something to do with the version of PHP or Wordpress.

Comment: You're using an old version of PHP which does not support the new array syntax. 10 answers coming in soon saying the same thing in different words

Comment: does it work with `return array(...)` ?

Comment: 1 in, 9 left...

Comment: Actually 2 in @HankyPanky

Comment: If you guys count my comment, I posted it like 3 seconds after Hanky posted his comment :P

Comment: Go to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and look for Example #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
return array(
            'result'  => true
        );
```